# Springtoolsuite -tomcat server or sysdeo plugin

Tags: tomcat

I have surfed many forums with similar threads but couldnt find real answers.

I have installed STS 2.3 and apache tomcat server.
I realized in servers, it already has apache tomcat (all versions) to associate  with apache installation (Apache tomcat home).Means i dont need separate plugin like sysdeo.

1.My confusion is what is the difference between Sysdeo tomcat plugin and apache tomcat server existing in Servers tab .
Sysdeo shows tomcat-start/stop icons(cat symbol) But tomcat in sts one wont.
2.Can we use sysdeo plugin with STS too?like with Eclipse we drop it in plugins directory.

3.Also without any projects deployed,starting tomcat outside eclipse/sts shows apache homepage on http://localhost:8080
but starting from inside sts/eclipse wont.Gets 404 message,but tomcat is running .
why is that so?Cant it be configured somehow to get nicer screen .